# How to register/resolve a type with one generic constructor parameter

Tags: c#, unity-container

I tried a lot of approches, but no luck.
How can I resolve the IWindowService?

This is what I have:

```
var c = new UnityContainer();
c.RegisterType<IvmMain, vmMain>("mvm");
c.RegisterType<IWindow, MainWindow>("mw");
c.RegisterType(typeof(IWindowService<IvmMain>), typeof(WindowService<vmMain>),"win",
                new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IWindow>("mw")),
                new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IvmMain>("mvm")));
```

The implementation of the window service:

```
public class WindowService<TViewModel> : IWindowService<TViewModel>
{
    readonly Window _win;
    TViewModel _vm;
    public WindowService(IWindow win, TViewModel vm)
    {
        _vm = vm;
        _win = win as Window;
        _win.DataContext = vm;
    }
```

**Error**:
The type WindowService does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (IWindow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example. In the scenario you have provided there's no reason for the named registrations, so I removed them. But I'm sure you can get it to work with them if you really want.

The key is to register `IWindowService` with:

`container.RegisterType(typeof (IWindowService<>), typeof (WindowService<>))`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Registering dependencies ...");

        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType(typeof (IWindowService<>), typeof (WindowService<>));

        container.RegisterType<IWindow, Window>();
        container.RegisterType<IvmMain, ViewModel>(); // Or possibly RegisterInstance ?

        var foo = container.Resolve<IWindowService<IvmMain>>();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IWindowService<T>
{
}

public interface IWindow
{
}

public interface IvmMain 
{
}

public class ViewModel : IvmMain
{ 
} 

public class Window : IWindow 
{ 
}

public class WindowService<TViewModel> : IWindowService<TViewModel>
{
    public WindowService(IWindow win, TViewModel vm)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: One further question (I can open a new Q for this):
I use constructor injection, so I don't use the resolve method explicitly.
If I had another `container.RegisterType<IvmMain, ViewModelOther>();` and wanted to use this one as a constrtuctor parameter in another class?
What would be the approach then?
Now I would need named registrations..without using `[Dependency]` attribute

Comment: Some way you really need to know what type you want to resolve. Constructor injection or not. There are a number of ways of doing that. Look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475047/breaking-solid-principles-in-multiple-implementation-of-an-interface/38475681#38475681

Comment: Short sum up, I accomplished this using the interface wrapping approach in order to circumvent the dependency on the Dependency attribute.
But using the Dependency attribute approach is less work. Good to know alternative ways of doing this.
Thanks again!

Comment: @Legends - Agreed. Using the Dependency attribute is simpler, but I find it less "clean".